# Number of nodes in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I read currently the [next tutorial](https://www.edureka.co/blog/hadoop-tutorial/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=blog-cta&utm_campaign=big-data-tutorial) about Hadoop using. Special interest for me is the number of nodes in the cluster.
I have now two machines: the master machine has 4 cpu's and the slave machine has 32 cpu's. 
In the chapter [Multinode Cluster in Hadoop 2.x](https://www.edureka.co/blog/setting-up-a-multi-node-cluster-in-hadoop-2.X?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=content-link&utm_campaign=hadoop-tutorial) the final result of nodes is just 2. Is it mean that two machines are in use for HDFS cluster and how I can know, that all 36 cpu's (4 from master + 32 from slave) are in use?

Comment: Yes, physically machines will be 2, but when you launch application you can see more than 2 `YARN childs` in parallel as per minimum cores and memory for YARN container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop platform has ResourceManager that knows about cluster resources. Number of cores and available RAM for container is configured in yarn on each hadoop node.

When you submit map-reduce job, ApplicationMaster will ask ResourceManager about available resources. Based on that, it will start up as many mappers / reducers as it can in parallel.

You can also see how many resources are available and how many were used by a particular job in Application UI.